# Design problem for DDD and User entity implementing Symfony's UserInterface

Tags: php, symfony, domain-driven-design

Why Symfony docs suggest to implement UserInterface interface on my domain User entity?

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/entity_provider.html

```
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable {}
```

To me it looks like this is breaking a basic DDD approach because my domain entities should never rely on something that resides outside the domain (in this case UserInterface is a Symfony component).

The problem is that Symfony's `UserPasswordEncoder` need `UserInterface` object to retrieve salt/password from users.

At the moment I have a very sketchy solution that it is not bullet-proof/scalable at all, so I'm looking for solutions.

Do I need to implement my own UserPasswordEncoder that can work directly on my Domain User entity?

Comment: You could do that and inject it as a dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To me it looks like this is breaking a basic DDD approach because my domain entities should never rely on something that resides outside the domain (in this case UserInterface is a Symfony component).

Theoretically speaking you are correct. Your Aggregates should not depend in any way to the Infrastructure.

Many frameworks are focused on enabling fast delivery of software, not on clean code. From what've seen, Symfony is more suitable for CRUD Entities, in simple domains, not for complex domains where DDD is more suitable. This means that maybe you should not use DDD in this domain, and maybe a CRUD entity would suffice.

Or maybe, if you think the `User` should indeed be a DDD Aggregate because it has complex behavior, then you should extract the `UserPassword` into its own CRUD Entity, that is not bound to DDD restrictions. Then, in your `User` Aggregate, you refer to the password only by ID, i.e. `private $passwordId;`.

> Do i need to implement my own UserPasswordEncoder that can work directly on my Domain User entity?

I think this would be the same thing as the framework's component, at least from the DDD point of view. The password hashing is an infrastructure component, no matter who's implementing it.

Comment: Ok your answer is very good, now let's say i'm using DDD+Onion and i'm developing this big project to be the most framework-agnostic possible. You say "I think this would be the same thing as the framework's component[...]. The password hashing is an infrastructure component, no matter who's implementing it." But there is a difference between having a component being a piece of my onion Infrastructure layer or being a piece of the framework available stack. If i need to switch to Laravel i should be able to do that without relying on framework components. What is your opinion on this?

Comment: @Matt I was saying that in the context of DDD. From the DDD POV, there is not notable difference between an infrastructure component made by you and one made by somebody else.

Comment: @Matt "If i need to switch to Laravel i should be able to do that without relying on framework components" - if you follow DDD strictly then yes, your domain should not be modified when you migrate the infrastructure, that's one of the purposes of DDD, to decouple the Domain from the Infrastructure.